# How can I get the grades of arithmetic quizzes? This is similar to Multiple Choice (MCQS) using ArrayList? What's wrong in my code?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, methods

In this question there is a separate array of question, key of question, options, Answers. The user seen the Questions and their four options and will enter the answer. The answer array will be compared with the key array which option is the true display correct answer

They can be entered on a single line, e.g., `34 7 13 100 81 3 9 10 321 12` might be the key for a 10-question quiz

IN THIS CODE I HAVE ONLY 2 QUESTION AND 2 KEYS AND 8 OPTIONS 4 FOR EACH QUESTION

```
 package p16;

     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class P16 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

     ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

      int C=0,w=0;

     items.add("What is your id");
     items.add(1, "what is your uni");

     ArrayList<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();

     key.add("2");
     key.add("2");

     ArrayList<String> Options = new ArrayList<String>();

     Options.add("1");
     Options.add("2");
     Options.add("3");
     Options.add("4");

     Options.add("1");
     Options.add("2");
     Options.add("3");
     Options.add("4");

     ArrayList<String> Answer = new ArrayList<String>();

     for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
     {
      System.out.println("items(i)");

       for(int k=0;k<12;k+=4)
     {
      Options.get(k);
      Options.get(k+1);
      Options.get(k+2);
      Options.get(k+3);
      }
      System.out.print("Enter :" );
      Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
       int a = S.nextInt();      
      }
       for(int j = 0;j<2;j++)
      {
        if(Answer.get(j).equals(key.get(j)))
        {C++;
                }
       else
       {w++;
       }}}
```

---

OUTPUT

```
     run:
     items(i)
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
     at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
     at p16.P16.main(P16.java:61)
     Java Result: 1
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Before we get to the code there is one over-riding problem here: you are trying to reuse a multi-choice algorithm, asking for option numbers but the questions you are asking are open-ended textual questions. For example "what is your name?". You cannot use a multi-choice approach for such questions. So start by deciding very clearly what questions you are asking and how the answers are to be used.

---

There are many problems with this code. It looks like you've tried to take a similar program and alter it, but you have not understood the original. My strong advice: Start again. Break the problem down into separate steps, test each step before trying to run the program as a whole.

Errors here:

Error 1: You get an answer from the user

```
int a = S.nextInt();
```

but never use the variable. You need to do something with that "a" value. See the next error.

Error 2: You have an ArrayList called Answer but never put any values in it. I suspect that your intention was to gather a set of answers and put them in the list but you haven't done that.

Modify your code to put the value of a into the Answer list.

Error 3: You have this code

```
 for(int k=0;k<12;k+=4)
 {
    Options.get(k);
    Options.get(k+1);
    Options.get(k+2);
    Options.get(k+3);
 }
```

it get values but doesn't do anything with them, so serves no purpose. It is here that your program is currently failing. You have put 8 values into the Options array (that's indexes 0 to 7) but you allow k to go higher than 7.

BUT: as I've said you have no reason to have this code as it currently stands. Why are you calling

```
  Options.get(k)
```

you don't use the result.

Error 4: You don't print your results.

Error 5: You print literally "items(i)", my guess is that you intended

```
System.out.println("items(" + i + ")" + items(i));
```

**Recommended action:**

Break the problem down into two steps:

1. Retrieve the answers from the user, store them in the Answer list. Verify this by printing the contents of the list.
2. Compare the Answer list with the expected answers (I guess that's what key is for). Print the results.

Comment: How does key.add(2) give the correct answer to "what is your name?" I think you are reusing something from a multiple choice question that doesn't work for names and universities.

Comment: That's not the way it works on StackOverflow, we don't just do the homework for someone. If you try, change your code as I've suggested, I'll help you fix it and other people may help too.

Comment: Question: what is your name?  <=== what options are possible here? I don't understand how you think you can have options when there are millions of possible answers. Right now I don't think you're making clear what you want your program to do. As your program stands you are expecting the user to type in a number in response to the question "What is your name". I don't understand how that makes sense.

Comment: dina forget the name its just an example it's code of MCQS multiple chioce  do you never saw MCQS?

Comment: Yes. Which is why I'm puzzled why you appeared to be applying MCQS techniques to questions that are not appropriate (name, uni?). If your published code includes immaterial lines it confuses anyone who might feel inclined to help you.  Begin by fixing the problem I identify as Error 3 above. Currently you add 8 options and allow k to go to 8, your 12 is wrong. Then don't just call get() do something with it, like for example print it. I will answer no further until you modify your code along those lines.